# Understanding the package structure (Module X.Y has no attribute Z)

Tags: python, packaging

This is the tree:

```
X
|_ setup.py
|_ X
   |_ someFile.py
   |_ __init__.py (empty)
   |_ Y
      |_ __init__.py (empty)
      |_ anotherFile.py
```

After running `pip install -e .`, I can run the following commands anywhere on my system:

```
import X
from X import someFile
from X.Y import anotherFile
```

But I cannot run:

```
from X import Y
Y.anotherFile

-> Module X.Y has no attribute "anotherFile".
```

I can fix that by filling the lower-level `__init__.py` with `from X.Y import anotherFile`, but that seems a bit odd.

Why is that? Is my understanding of python packages wrong?

Disclaimer: Someone might have asked this before, but the question is so generic that I had difficulties finding the right post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's simple actually. For `from X import Y`, the imported module is the `__init__.py` file in directory `Y` but not all other files.

But I think the real question is, Why?

Let's say `anotherFile` is the only module you want, so you import `anotherFile` by `from X.Y import anotherFile`. But actually you have also imported `X` and `Y`. Although you cannot access them by `X` or `Y`, but if you `import sys` and `sys.modules.keys()`, you can see these modules as `X` and `X.Y`. And you can access the attributes in `Y` by `sys.modules["X.Y"].a  # suppose there is`. That means the `__init__.py` file under directory `Y` has been executed.

OK, so now if importing `Y` or `X` will also execute all files under that package, guess what? Yes, even though you just need `anotherFile` module, all files including directory `Y` under directory `X` will be executed. And these files also import other files and so on... With just one import, the whole project is imported.

Comment: So you are saying that I should not be able to run `from X import Y; Y.anotherFile`? A colleague of mine stated that his code depends on that and he did not understand why it did not work for me.

Comment: If you `from . import anotherFile` in `__init__.py` under `Y` directory, then you can do that. I guess your colleague has done it without awareness.